# Deploy a GPU intensive Cloud Run service on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

I have a application which is GPU intensive. I have tried deploying this on GKE cluster which is GPU enabled and that went well. Now I want to run my application as a Cloud run service on GKE, I did not find any option for specifying GPU's while creating a Cloud run service. Can anyone please help me out. TIA

I was following this article 
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/setup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Run on Kubernetes does not support GPUs.