# Force Google Cloud Run containers to be scheduled on nodes with a GPU

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run, knative-serving

Is there a way to force services deployed using Google Cloud Run for Anthos (hosted on GKE) to be scheduled to node pools that have a GPU?

I created a Kubernetes cluster by going to `Kubernetes -> Create Cluster -> GPU Accelerated Computing`. This created a Kubernetes cluster with a `gpu-pool-1` node pool, containing nodes with a GPU, and a `standard-pool-1` node pool, containing nodes without a GPU.

Is there a way I can deploy Cloud Run containers to nodes having a GPU? Maybe by configuring a custom namespace or something?

---

Note that there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56327252/deploy-a-gpu-intensive-cloud-run-service-on-gke) from close to a year ago, but I do not think that the accepted answer ("Cloud Run on Kubernetes does not support GPUs") is entirely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [hot topic](https://github.com/knative/serving/pull/6405) on Knative serving development.

Not possible for now to have node selector and toleration when your pods is spawn with Knative serving, but the team is working on a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the reply! I found [another issue](https://github.com/knative/serving/issues/1998) on the knative/serving GitHub page that suggests it is possible to set `limits: nvidia.com/gpu: 1` on the service Configuration. Would that not work? I am having trouble figuring out how to modify the Configuration of a running service (total neub here...).

Comment: You can define a `requests` and `limits` on your container definition but I'm not sure that the right pool will be use. If you have only pool of nodes with gpus, maybe that the limit has an effect, but in your case it won't help to select the pool with GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

There does seem to be a way to get this to work, at least in a hacky way, as described [here](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/services/creating-services/).

The knative `Service` configuration file does seem to accept and respect the `limits: nvidia.com/gpu: 1` argument. While the Cloud Run interface does not allow us to specify this argument ourselves, we can use the `kubectl` CLI to manually deploy knative services defined by a yaml file which contains this argument.

First, we need to create a GKE cluster with a cpu node pool, a gpu node pool, and Cloud Run for Anthos enabled. This can be accomplished by going to `Kubernetes Engine -> Create Cluster -> Selecting "GPU Accelerated Computing" on the left cluster templates bar -> Checking the "Enable Cloud Run for Anthos"`. Once the cluster is created, we can click the "connect" button and start a cloud shell. Here, we can create a `service.yaml` file which defines our knative service. For example, we can adapt the `service.yaml` file from the [knative documentation](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/getting-started-knative-app/#configuring-your-deployment) but specify that this service requires a GPU:

```
# service.yaml
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1 # Current version of Knative
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworld-go # The name of the app
  namespace: default # The namespace the app will use
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/knative-samples/helloworld-go # The URL to the image of the app
          env:
            - name: TARGET # The environment variable printed out by the sample app
              value: "Go Sample v1"
          resources:
            limits:
              nvidia.com/gpu: 1 # The service must be run on a machine with at least one GPU
```

We can deploy this service using:

```sh
kubectl apply -f service.yaml
```

and check its status using:

```sh
kubectl get ksvc helloworld-go
```

The `helloworld-go` service should only be scheduled on nodes containing a GPU. The service should show up on the Cloud Run dashboard just like the other Cloud Run for Anthos services.

Comment: I think there is a confusion between the resource requests and the resources limits. The request is "what the pod need to be run on the Node, if the node can't allow enough resource, look for another node or create another one". The limit is "The pod is authorize to use resources up to this limit. If it goes over, terminate it."

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I think I understand what you are saying, but for my very simple use-case it does seem to work. If I deploy the `helloworld-go` service without the `limits: nvidia.com/gpu: 1`, it goes to the cpu node pool. If I deploy the service with those limits, it goes to the gpu node pool, autoscaling a new VM if it is currently at 0. I haven't tested this extensively, but it does seem to fulfill my use-case of running a container which requires a GPU and will only be accessed several times a week.

Comment: Is it work? With a node pool that scale to 0? Wow, very strange. But, if that solve your issue, it's great! If you update your cluster (KNative or Kubernetes versions) I recommend you to perform tests to be sure that this behavior is still the same, it looks like to be a side effect!